# Spring/Java Creating Templates for MimeMessages

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I want my application to send out emails for certain events. But I want the email being sent to always come from the same address. So instead of setting the from every single time I just want to create a bean template and use that. Here's my config:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="event.email")
public class MailConfig {
    private String from;

    @Bean
    MimeMessage templateMessage() {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();
        message.setFrom(from);
        return mailMessage;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }
}
```

And here's my mail service:

```
@Component
public class MailService {
    private MimeMessage template;

    public MailService(MimeMessage template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void send() {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(mailTemplate);
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

The issue with this is that the config has an error: `Unhandled exception: javax.mail.MessagingException`. I can put a try/catch in there or make the method throw the exception very easily but I don't know if that's best practice when creating beans.

Is this best practice? If not, what's the better way to do this?

Comment: Any authentization?

Comment: No. No authentication

Comment: That's it what is missing.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis that is not the issue. You did not understand my question. This is not a runtime error nor would it have anything to do with authentication. This is a syntax error. The `setFrom` method throws the `MessagingException` which needs to be either caught or rethrown. I'm asking about best practices for this scenario

Comment: The `MimeMessage` class looks to be a stateful class. Why would you want to create a bean out of it in this case?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe so whats the best way to set a from address for all my emails without having to do it every single time I compose a message? I just want to set the from once at app startup and never again since it's the same every time

Comment: @Richard create a service layer/class that will do this for you. You shouldn't bean stateful classes.